# highcharts-angular not rendering the chart

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am using `Angular 7`,  `highcharts` and `highcharts-angular` to render 3 donut charts. However, they are not rendering for some reason.

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qaa4cv) to demonstrate the issue.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular_highcharts/angular_highcharts_configuration_syntax.htm) to make it work, but it's not working.

All 3 charts are getting the options properly, but the charts are not rendering.

```
<div id="chart{{chartIndex}}">
<highcharts-chart>
  [Highcharts] = "highcharts" 
  [options] = "options"
  style = "width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;"
</highcharts-chart>
</div>
```

Comment: See this tutorial. It is more relevant. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/blob/master/README.md#getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have a typo in your html, in your `hc-chart` component:

```
<highcharts-chart>
  [Highcharts] = "highcharts" 
  [options] = "options"
  style = "width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;"
</highcharts-chart>
```

Your options are not being passed to the `highcharts-chart` component.

Change your code to:

```
<highcharts-chart
  [Highcharts] = "highcharts" 
  [options] = "options"
  style = "width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;">
</highcharts-chart>
</div>
```

Notice the moving of the angle brack `>`.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmugml) is the updated StackBlitz.